# jquery .each with .outerHeight function affects all divs

Tags: jquery, function, each, reusability, outerheight

I have multiple divs using the same html, with variable heights. I am trying to calculate the height of div `.content`, then use that value to set the height of the `.sections` div. Currently, this function is only affecting the last div of its type. How can I make this function reusable so it works on every div on the page?

```
var currentHeight = 0;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('.content').each(function() {
      currentHeight = jQuery(this).outerHeight();
    });

    jQuery('.sections').each(function() {
      jQuery(this).css('height', currentHeight/2);
    });

});
```

Example HTML:

```
<div class="sections"></div>
  <div class="content">content with a height of 200px</div>
<div class="sections"></div>

other html....

<div class="sections"></div>
  <div class="content">content with a height of 400px</div>
<div class="sections"></div>
```

So, the first two `.sections` would get a height of 100px, and the last two `.sections` would get a height of 200px.

**UPDATE:**
**I've found a solution based on Forty3's answer! Can this be written more DRY though?**

Forty3's solution worked for me, with some minor tweaking:

```
// With the .content FOLLOWING the .section - use the following:
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('.bigImageSections').each(function() {

      var ic = jQuery(this).next('.translatedContent');
      if (ic.length > 0) {
        jQuery(this).css('height', jQuery(ic).outerHeight() / 2);
      }

      var ict = jQuery(this).prev('.translatedContent');
      if (ict.length > 0) {
        jQuery(this).css('height', jQuery(ict).outerHeight() / 2);
      }

    });
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the MAXIMUM height of all possible `.content` DIVs and then set the height of all `.sections` DIVs to 1/2 of that height? Because, as it stands, your `.each(...)` will keep resetting the value in `currentHeight` until it finalizes with the last `.content` it finds.

Comment: No. I want to find the exact height of specific divs. I've updated my question with an example html structure.

Comment: Your `.content` **are not inside** `.sections`

Comment: This is intentional. I am anticipating both `.section` elements to be intelligently sized based on the adjacent `.content` element.

Answer (score 0):

Run through your `.section` elements recalculating their height based on the height of the inner `.content` element:

```
// If the .content was inside the .section - use the following
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('.sections').each(function() {
      var ic = jQuery('.content', this);
      if (ic.length > 0) {
        jQuery(this).css('height', jQuery(ic).outerHeight() / 2);
      }
    });
});

// With the .content FOLLOWING the .section - use the following:
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('.sections').each(function() {
      var ic = jQuery(this).next('.content');
      if (ic.length > 0) {
        jQuery(this).css('height', jQuery(ic).outerHeight() / 2);
      }
    });
});
```

Edit: Forgot to divide by 2.

BTW: I noticed in your sample HTML, your `.content` was not contained within your `.section` .. was this intentional? If so, are you anticipating that the `.section` elements be intelligently sized based on preceding or following `.content` elements?

Comment: Yes, this is intentional. I am anticipating both `.section` elements to be intelligently sized based on the adjacent `.content` element.